# CSS Transitions - Why won't they fire on class-change of freshly added content?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

Here's an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/5652844

I'm creating a new element, setting a class, appending it to a parent and immediately switch the class so an transition shall trigger. Like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("class", "left");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.setAttribute("class", "right");
```

The classes simply set a `left` value, while the div has `transition: left .5s ease;`.

Now, for some unknown reason the transition only triggers when I add a short delay (10-20ms seem to work) before the second `setAttribute()`.

My question is: Is there a cleaner way to do this? I've tried jQuery's `append` and `addClass`, which shows the same behavior. jQuery UI's `switchClass` seems to work, but isn't there a better way instead of relying on random delay values?

Comment: I'd guess its because without the delay, there's no chance for the browser to do an initial draw, which would give the element some place to transition from. When the JavaScript is done, the browser draws the element, and it only sees that it has the `right` class, and was never aware of the `left`.

Comment: Yeah, that's my suspicion too. It almost seems as if the element get added to the DOM with `class="right"`. I don't suppose there's a magical event or callback that lets you know when the element is in the DOM and has finished drawing?

Comment: No, there won't be a callback. Since the browser view responds to JavaScript's manipulations, but isn't *part of* JavaScript, you just need to make your JS cooperate with the UI to achieve the effect you need. Making the class change an asynchronous action that happens after a short duration *(like you're doing)* is probably going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your example, you can find my version here: http://dabblet.com/gist/5652939

Basically, what I did was simply modify the CSS: I added "animation: toright 5s" to your div style ("toright" is just the name of the animation, you can put anything there instead) and then I used the @keyframes rule, like this:

```
@keyframes toright
{
    from {left:50px;}
    to {left:500px;}
}
```

toright is of course the name I gave to the animation, so it can be referenced here. It's like referencing any page element, like divs, textareas etc, only you put @keyframes to specify that you're going to write down the steps of your animation.
First step is that the div has a css attribute "left" of 50 px, as you specified in your code, and then the last step is modify the attribute specified above to be 500px. The transition will take 5s, as specified in the div attribute "animation".
I hope it's clear! For more information you may want to read [this MDN article about CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Oh and of course I removed all the JS code that you used to trigger the transition!

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty nice CSS only solution! While I think I can make my specific case work with this (And I'll be sure to check out animations more), it sadly doesn't explain why those delays are needed. I'm currently looking into the various DOM events, but haven't found anything suitable yet, so I'm open for more answers.

Comment: Actually on Chrome it does work with the timeout set to "0", so maybe it depends on the browser you're using?

Comment: Once you remove the `setInterval()` wrapping, you'll probably see no animation on Chrome either. By the way, the only real solution I've found so far is abusing animations like this: http://dabblet.com/gist/5653047 (based on http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) . I had tried various DOM events before, but they all seemed to fire too soon..

Comment: Oh, so you wanted to do the javascript animation without setTimeout() at all? Well of course it's not possible, to animate anything in Javascript you need to use setInterval() if you want to repeat the animation, setTimeout() to execute it once. Without these methods it's not possible to make a nice animation effect, the second time you set the attribute will simply overwrite the first one in a matter of milliseconds. The best you can see in that case is the div flickering on load :)

Comment: What I really wanted is to be able to create elements on-demand from javascript, and slide/fade them into view (only a single run). The core of the problem seems to be that the various inserting methods don't seem to run synchronously.

Comment: Ok, see if it's the kind of thing you wanted, I made a jsfiddle (since on dabblet I couldn't import JQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/RyFsd/3/ I used JQuery functions show() and animate(), more information here: http://api.jquery.com/show/ and here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Ah, I should've been more clear in my question. When doing animation, I'd like to avoid `animate()` as it can't benefit from hardware acceleration like CSS animations or transform. But I'll accept your answer nonetheless, as it seems to be the only one that came up. I solved my problem in the meanwhile like this: https://gist.github.com/silverwind/5653378.